# Aplanar covering of $S^1 \vee S^1$?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology

Can someone provide an aplanar covering of $S^1 \vee S^1$? What if I insist on it being finite degree? (This question is motivated by the diagram in the first chapter of Hatcher's Algebriac Topology, where he discusses covering spaces. There all the examples he gives are planar.)

Here is an equivalent question: Wikipedia informs me that trees with a countable number of vertices are planar. (As seems reasonable, since we can evenly fit a finite number of vertices in to each compact set in some exhaustion of the plane.) Thus the universal covering is planar. If a group acts by a covering space action on planar graph, is the quotient a planar graph? A positive answer would provide a negative answer to my first question. A negative answer would provide a positive answer to my question (even if non-constructive).

I'm thinking about this, but I don't know anything about graph theory beyond the basic definitions that have come up in studying topology, so I'd rather ask here first in order to prevent wasting my time.

If one exists (and is reasonably accessible) please tell me but hide the answer somehow (I think spoiler tags are possible here). In that case I think it would be a good exercise for me to find it.

Comment: Universal covering is a tree, so certainly planar. But I'm not sure about finite degree coverings. They seem intricate.

Comment: I'm not sure that being a tree implies that it is planar. For instance, if I connect the right side of uncountable number of edges to a single vertex the result is a tree that is not second countable. But every subspace of the plane must be second countable.

Comment: "Every tree is a bipartite graph and a median graph. Every tree with only countably many vertices is a planar graph." From wikipedia. So you are correct.

Comment: (Since $|F(a,b)| = |\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} W(n)|$, where $W(n)$ are the words of length $n$, each of which has cardinality bounded by $4^n$.)

Comment: My counter example does not meet this criterion because there are uncountably many vertices at the left sides of the attached edges.

Comment: (Alternatively, if there were an uncountable number of vertices, then the image of the vertices in the embedding would have a limit point, whereas the vertices in the graph are discrete.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is precisely one finite degree aplanar covering of $S^1 \vee S^1$. It has degree $5$ and the covering space is homeomorphic to $K_5$ (a complete graph on $5$ vertices). The covering map sends every vertex of $K_5$ to the basepoint, outer edges of $K_5$ to one circle and inner edges to the other circle.

[image]

Motivation: by [Kuratowski theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem) a graph is nonplanar precisely when it contains $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$. Now every vertex in the cover of $S^1 \vee S^1$ has an even degree while $K_{3,3}$ has vertices of odd degree. Therefore it's enough to check for the presence of $K_5$ in the covering.

Now, any degree $n$ covering of $S^1 \vee S^1$ has $n$ vertices each of degree $4$ and $2n$ edges. Suppose that this covering contains a copy of $K_5$. Then there is no way to connect the rest of the vertices to the rest of the covering (informally, we used up all of the degrees of vertices). Therefore $K_5$ itself is actually the only aplanar covering space.